# Insert and update methods of dao are not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

For some reason the `addUser()`, `updateUser()` methods are not working.
Can someone please look at the code and figure out where I'm making mistake?

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(UserId, FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Email, UserName, Password) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        // Parameters start with 1
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,user.getUserId());  
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getLastName());           
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getJobTitle());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getUserName());                 
        preparedStatement.setString(7, user.getPassword());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateUser(User user) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update users  set Email=?,  Password=? where Username=?");

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getEmail());  
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getUserName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPassword());


        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please note that I don't have much experience in java.
There is no error being printed, this is why I can't tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your updateUser(), the order of the parameters is wrong.  From your sql statement, it should be email, password and then username.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getEmail());  
preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());    
preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getUserName());
```

Also, I suggest you to add a "finally" block to close the statement and the result set.